# How to get profit loss from SQL data from a single table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

this is my table

```
item_name   expense   income    balance     
hammer         1        0        613.90       
cde            0        1        530.10
hammer         0        1        300.00
```

the columns expense/income represent if the item is in profit or loss.
if expense is 1 it is in loss and if income is 1 the item is sold.

i want data to be shown in such a manner that for each item i can see how much profit i gained or loss i took.
example

```
item_name     Loss     Profit   
hammer       613.90    300.00   
cde            0       530.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like aggregation:

```
select item_name,
       sum(case when expense = 1 then balance else 0 end) as loss,
       sum(case when income = 1 then balance else 0 end) as profit
from t
group by item_name;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much